# Can't write in a file in the external storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I need to write a simple text in a file "test.txt".

This is my code:

```
String SDCARD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

String FILENAME = "test.txt";

File outfile = new File(SDCARD+File.separator+FILENAME);

if (outfile.exists()) { Log.d("Filename","the file exists"); }

Log.d("Filename",SDCARD+File.separator+FILENAME);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile,true);

fos.write("just a test".getBytes());
fos.close();
```

In the manifest there is the permission request:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        package="com.xrobot.john.texttest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and the targetsdkversion is 15.

Logcat display this:

```
12-01 12:57:26.178  29663-29663/com.xrobot.john.softkeyboard D/Filename﹕ the file exists
12-01 12:57:26.178  29663-29663/com.xrobot.john.softkeyboard D/Filename﹕ /storage/emulated/0/test.txt
```

and the file text.txt is always empty.

Why ?

Comment: don't use `getExternalStorageDirectory` directly. Use `getExternalFilesDir`. It will return a path on the sdcard where only your app can write (under `/sdcard/Android/data/yourpackage`. How are you reading the file back?

Comment: try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: And for marshmallow and above you have to take the external storage permission at run time.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: I am reading the file by tapping it and opening it with chrome or a simple text editor

Comment: @SagarGangawane In my case I am using targedsdkversion = 15. So I don't need to request permission at run time

Comment: and on which version of android are you  testing it ?

Comment: I am testing it on Android 6.

Comment: That means you need to ask for runtime permissions.

Comment: go into your app settings on the device and look for "permissions"

Comment: In the app settings the READ/WRITE permission is already ON. So it doesn't seem a permission problem.

Comment: help me please :(

Comment: Add `fos.flush()` and `fos.getFD().sync()` before `fos.close()`. Do not use `getBytes()`, but instead wrap the `FileOutputStream` in a `PrintWriter`. After closing the file, use `MediaScannerConnection` and its static `scanFile()` method to ensure that the `MediaStore` knows about the file and has its proper size.

Comment: @CommonsWare done, but the file is still empty.

Comment: Use `adb shell ls` to examine the actual filesystem and see if your file exists with the proper size.

Comment: @vrundpurohit The READ permission is not necessary. The WRITE one implicitly includes it.

Comment: @Rotwang `outfile.exists()`, for that i guess it is necessary.

Comment: @vrundpurohit No, it's NOT.

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps missing permission for reading that file.
Also, you are missing `fos.flush()` between `fos.write()` and `fos.close()` , that can easily cause that unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Use a buffered writer to write your string to a file

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try
{
    writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(SDCARD+File.separator+FILENAME));
    writer.write( "just a test");

}
catch ( IOException e)
{
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        if ( writer != null)
        writer.close( );
    }
    catch ( IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```